# what exactly ruby |variable| returns and why should I use it?

Tags: ruby

I am following a rails tutorial and in my `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` I am writing the following code to make the email address down case:

```
before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
```

But what are the significance of this `|user|` in ruby? Previously I have seen it inside a ruby loop. I am not getting a proper keyword for search.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ |user| user.email = email.downcase }
```

This is a block. `user` is a block parameter. `before_save` is a method that takes a block, saves it and calls later, passing current instance of User as parameter.

Comment: Now you have enough keywords for more googling. :)